# exclude specific time for duration calculation

Tags: dax

I have this dataset and calculated Datediff1 using below calculated column. Issue is no execution take place between 12am to 5am but when i calculate duration it adds extra 5 hours which is not giving exact duration, Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

```
Datediff1 = 
ABS(
    DATEDIFF (
        CALCULATE (
            MIN ( OTC[End Date] ),
            FILTER ( 
                OTC, 
                OTC[Index] = EARLIER ( OTC[Index] )+1  
            )
        ),
        OTC[End Date],
        MINUTE
    )
)
```

Comment: Like if time lies between 12am to 5 am and after that then these 5 hour are added.i dont need this only actual time

Comment: Hi, can you provide a table with expected result?

Comment: Table i shared is expected result with Datediff1 column have values with lower duration where time lies between 12 to 5 am

Comment: The expected result means the exact output you want to achieve. The question is not that clear.

Comment: I want Duration between dates as i created Datediff1 column but the only issue is when  end date is between 12 am and 5am like execution start on 8pm and end before 12am and then start after 5 am and end 6 am the actual duration is 4 hours but it will show 9 hours i need 4 hours in datediff1 column